# Open external js form on new window

Tags: javascript, forms, window, external

Having problem to open form in new window, script is pulled from external service.
Take a look  [CODE on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ljuboja/XeAcq/)

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a target attribute to the form after its been rendered;

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fixform() {
   //ism is created by the opentable.com script
   document.forms["ism"].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="fixform();">
    <div id="book-table">
    <div id="OT_searchWrapperAll">
            <script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://www.opentable.com/ism/?rid=35449"></script>
            <noscript id="OT_noscript">
                <a href="http://www.opentable.com/single.aspx?rid=35449&restref=35449&rtype=ism">Reserve Now on OpenTable.com</a>
            </noscript>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update** Try removing the `onload="fixform();"` and use the jQuery equivalent;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   document.forms["ism"].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
});
```

Comment: dont work :-(
I  put script in footer and header, but no lack.
Maybe I dont doing something right or not working

Comment: What browser are you using and does the form just open in the current page?

Comment: browsers:firefox 4, and google chrome.Yes form open in same window

Comment: Odd, if I copy/paste/save that page in ffox4, ie8 & chrome I get a new tab as expected

Comment: hmm
i take a look, my fault i guess

Comment: @alex-K
Dont get it, also work for me when cp paste save, but on my staging site fail :-(
here is the [link](http://staging.redcoats.co.uk) to view source of working site, if you whish.

thx

Comment: try to put this into script tag in head, but not working,again.:-(
to put this in external file?

Comment: Your using it in the head **before** jQuery is included so its not working, add it after. Also add an alert("xxx") before the setAttribute to verify that its being called.